# In how many ways can 2016 be written as a sum $ a_0 + 2\cdot a_1 + 2^2 \cdot a_2 +\cdots + 2^k \cdot a_k $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In how many ways can 2016 be written as a sum 
 $ a_0 + 2 \cdot a_1 + 2^2 \cdot a_2 + \cdots + 2^k \cdot a_k $

if $ a_i $ are only allowed to take values $0,1,2$ or $3$ ?

Steps would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know generating functions?

Comment: Yes but I do not see how it is going to help. I used mod of the whole equation until mod 32 , and the whole process gets a little bit tedious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

**Easy approach**:

Note that each $a_i$ can be written as $c_i+2d_i$ where $c_i,d_i\in\{0,1\}$, and this this is the same as counting the number of ways to write $2016$ as $c+2d$, with the $c_i,d_i$ the binary digits of the $c,d$ respectively.

**Generating function approach**:

Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways of writing $n$ in this form. Then notice that:

$$\begin{align}
\sum f(n)x^n &= \prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(1+x^{2^i}+x^{2\cdot 2^i} + x^{3\cdot 2^i}\right)\\
&=\prod_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{i+2}}-1}{x^{2^{i}}-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}
\end{align}$$

Basically, all the denominators except the first ones get cancelled by a numerator.

We then see, again, that $f(n)$ is the number of ways of writing $n=c+2d$.

---

As the way of mathematics often is, I did the complicated way first, and then when I saw the answer, was able to find the "easy" solution.

Comment: In regards to your "complicated precedes easy" observation, I find that to be true annoyingly often.

Comment: I understand most of it but how to compute the number of ways of writing 2016 as it was said? I thinking about precise numer. I just don't understand the last sentence of your solution.

Comment: The last sentence is just a comment on math in general. I didn't actually write out a formula, figuring I'd leave that to the questioner. Given $n$, how many ways can you write $n$ as the sum $c+2d$ where $c,d\geq 0$?